# Require JS with CDN jQuery and Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I am new to Reqire.JS and i am not able to make the fancybox work with Google CDN jQuery.

My file structure is:

```
index.html/
├── js/
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── app/
│   |   ├── main.js
│   ├── lib/
│   |   ├── require.js
│   |   ├── jquery.fancybox.js
│   |   ├── jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
│   |   ├── jquery.fancybox-media.js
│   |   ├── jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js
```

**app.js**

```
requirejs.config({
    "baseUrl": "js/lib",
    "paths": {
      "app": "../app",
      "jquery": "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min",
      "jquery.fancybox": "jquery.fancybox",
      "jquery.fancybox-thumbs": "jquery.fancybox-thumbs",
      "jquery.fancybox-media": "jquery.fancybox-media",
      "jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack": "jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack"
    }
});

requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

**main.js**

```
define(["jquery", "jquery.fancybox-media", "jquery.fancybox-thumbs", "jquery.fancybox", "jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack"], function ($) {
    $(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
        <script data-main="js/app" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="fancybox" href="myImage.jpg" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="">
            <h5>Click</h5>
        </a>
    </body>
```

I am still geting the error of jQuery not defined. I can see my fancybox libraries and jQuery  on DOM but nothing happens.

Comment: I think should be like this: `jquery: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min",`. Remove `brackets - " "` at `jquery` from document: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: @vanloc are you sure?  have tried it and not working. btw in both situation (with or without brackets), i can see the jquery at the DOM. in documentations it shows that without brackets but in examples, it has done with brackets.

Comment: I just see your code correctly. I found in the document don't need `" "`. So, I think should remove that.

Comment: @vanloc i have removed braces and yet not working. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You possibly need to shim the fancybox files as documented [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html).

Something like:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'Scripts',
    paths: {
        "app": "../App",
        "jquery": 'jquery-3.1.1' //Or use cdn
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery.fancybox": ["jquery"]
    }
});

requirejs(["app/index"]);
```

The error you are getting is quite possibly due to require trying to load both jQuery and fancybox files asynchronously, receiving the fancybox one first (as it is smaller) and not being able to use it as the jQuery file is not loaded yet and so erroring.